# Align points to edge using common attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, alignment

I have two layers, one with points that represents house numbers, and another one that represent the edge  of the square, these layers have an attribute in commun, so I´m looking for a way I can use this attribute to  align the points layers to the edge of the square:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS includes a toolbox tool called [Snap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm) which will do exactly what you want.  Unfortunately, this tool only works with an advanced or standard license.

All ArcGIS tools respect selections.  If you select all the points with an attribute, and all the lines with the similar attribute then run the snap tool  you will only snap the points you want to the lines you want.

You can automate this selection and snapping process with model builder iterators, or with Python but you should post those questions in different posts.